# Qt view to display data columns vertically in pairs

Tags: python, qt, model-view, pyside6

I’m currently wrapping my mind around model/view programming using Qt via PySide6 in Python. I’m looking for a view that supports displaying the column data of data rows *vertically* in pairs (for simplification I’m only assuming 2 columns here, A and B). To illustrate this, in a QTableView, data would be displayed like this (for columns A and B):

A B
A B
…

While I want it to display like this:

A
B

A
B

…

Could someone point me to a good starting point to achieve this? I initially played around with displaying data using QDataWidgetMapper for widgets within a QScrollArea, but this doesn’t feel like the right way to do it.

Comment: Take a look at QTreeView, you would then show each column under separate branches.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I had ruled out QTreeView at the beginning, but looking at it again now, it makes total sense to use it for this kind of display.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I came up with based on Remarkod’s suggestion to use QTreeView. This leaves some space between the pairs of data, but that’s fine for me. I guess it would be possible to completely hide the root items somehow, instead of just leaving them empty and unselectable.

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel, Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTreeView


class RootItem(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Make root items unselectable
        self.setEditable(False)
        self.setFlags(Qt.NoItemFlags)


class ItemA(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText("A")


class ItemB(QStandardItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setText("B")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.treeModel = QStandardItemModel()
        self.rootNode = self.treeModel.invisibleRootItem()

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)

        rootItem_1 = RootItem()
        item_a1 = ItemA()
        item_b1 = ItemB()

        rootItem_2 = RootItem()
        item_a2 = ItemA()
        item_b2 = ItemB()

        rootItem_1.appendRow(item_a1)
        rootItem_1.appendRow(item_b1)
        self.rootNode.appendRow(rootItem_1)

        rootItem_2.appendRow(item_a2)
        rootItem_2.appendRow(item_b2)
        self.rootNode.appendRow(rootItem_2)

        # Expand all items, make them unexpandable, and hide decoration for root items
        self.treeView.setItemsExpandable(False)
        self.treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.treeView.expandAll()

        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeView)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_win = MainWindow()
    main_win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```